# How to automatically sort google spreadsheets by a row

Tags: sorting, google-sheets

I'm trying to make my google spreadsheet automatically sort the order of columns in my spreadsheet by the value in a row

For example, the following spreadsheet:

| 1 | header | header2 | header3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | filler | filler2 | filler3 |
| 3 | 4 | 1 | 7 |
| 4 | testA | testB | testC |
| 5 | testD | testE | testF |
| -- | --------- | --------- | --------- |

would become the following spreadsheet:

| 1 | header | header2 | header3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | filler3 | filler | filler2 |
| 3 | 7 | 4 | 1 |
| 4 | testC | testA | testB |
| 5 | testF | testD | testE |
| -- | --------- | --------- | --------- |

How would I go about accomplishing this?

Comment: I'm confused as to how you're wanting to sort this. The 1 in header 2 should go to header 3? Can you provide a little more detail on exactly what you're trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SORT(TRANSPOSE(A1:C10), 2, 1))
```

[image]